# Reactjs: How to check each of array index containing the value or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, syntax-error, typeerror

This is my array:

```
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([
   {
     "id": 1,
     "barcode": "8851907264888",
     "qty" : 1
   }, 
   {
     "id": 2,
     "barcode": "8857124022072",
     "qty": 1
   }
  ]);
```

this is my function:

```
  const hasBarcode = (arr, barcode) => arr.some(el => el.barcode === barcode);

  const handleUpdate=()=>{
   let x = 8851907264888;
   for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
     if(hasBarcode(arr[i], x) == true){
        let newArr = [...arr];
        newArr[i].qty = newArr[i].qty + 1;
        setArr(newArr);       
       }
    }
  }
```

My problem is in the `for loop`, I would like to check each of array index, if each index contains the same `barcode`as `x`, i would like to make addtion for `qty + 1` for that specific index. But here it shown error as `Cannot read property 'some' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error in your code you passing an object to hasBarcode()   not array
also you can do it like this

```
  const handleUpdate = () => {
    let x = 8851907264888;
    let newArr = arr.map((obj) => {
      if (obj.barcode && obj.barcode == x) {
        obj.qty = obj.qty + 1;
      }
      return obj;
    });
    setArr(newArr);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
  const hasBarcode = (arr, barcode) => arr.some(el => el.barcode === barcode);

  const handleUpdate=()=>{
   let x = 8851907264888;
   for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
     if(hasBarcode(arr, x) == true){
        let newArr = [...arr];
        newArr[i].qty = newArr[i].qty + 1;
        setArr(newArr);       
       }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error in your code is here

```
if(hasBarcode(arr[i], x) == true){
```

because you are trying to apply a method whose first argument is an array, to an object.

The correct one should be    `if(hasBarcode(arr, x) == true){`

You could do the following, though, using `filter` and `forEach` functions of `Array`:

```
  const handleUpdate = () => {
    let x = 8851907264888;
    let newArr = [...arr];
    newArr.filter(el => el.barcode === barcode).forEach(el => el.qty++);
    setArr(newArr);  
  }
```